# Adding Section/Chapter label to slide header

Tags: powerpoint, naming

I'm wondering if Powerpoint has a feature where I can automatically add a formatted header to each slide that displays the section and/or chapter. I'm presenting my thesis, and it is divided into sections, like "method" or "evaluation", and I would love it if I could automatically display that in the header of each slide. Preferrably, this would be automatically fetched from my powerpoint sections.

I want this look, which I'm currently producing manually for each slide.

[image]

Comment: You need PowerPoint's help to auto insert/update "1.Introduction" and "4" on the top only, or including "The Modern ..." line?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a bit of starter code to get you the name of the section each slide belongs to.
Over to you to provide the code to add the text to each slide and position/format it.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oSl As Slide
        ' Make sure there ARE sections
        If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count > 0 Then
        For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
            Debug.Print GetSection(oSl)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Function GetSection(oSl As Slide) As String
' Returns the name of the section that this slide belongs to.

With oSl
    Debug.Print .sectionIndex
    GetSection = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(.sectionIndex)
End With
```

Comment: Someone managed to do the full macro code?

Comment: If so, they haven't posted it here. Have you tried writing the code yourself? If so, post it here and people will help you solve any problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint has no function like this built-in.

However, like most Office products, PowerPoint does have a very powerful VBA macro engine, which would certainly be capable of doing this.

Your macro would have to capture the Section name based on whatever parameters you choose to use to mark that, and then it could place that information anywhere you please within subsequent slides.

Because slides are more about visual layout than programmatic auto-creation, this is something you'd have to build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA code provided [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ppt-using-section-names-in-footer/2b844798-2afa-4216-9ba5-5d066ac4dcca) by John SR Wilson worked for me:

```
Sub secfoot()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim b_found As Boolean
If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count > 0 Then
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
osld.HeadersFooters.Footer.Visible = True
For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
If oshp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
If oshp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderFooter Then _
oshp.TextFrame.TextRange = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(osld.sectionIndex)
End If
Next oshp
Next osld
End If
End Sub
```

Make sure to have a footer text field on each slide (e.g. through the slide master view: Insert - Header&Footer). Then copy-paste the code in a new macro and run.